# ABAP CDS view how to use CASE and SUM together

Tags: abap, cds

I have a scenario where I have to use CASE and SUM in an CDS VIEW SQL statement and I cannot add net_val to the group by statement. Is there a way to use CASE and SUM together

```
case when sum( net_val ) < 0 then 'DEBIT' 
     when sum( net_val ) > 0 then 'CREDIT'
end as DEBIT_CREDIT_STATUS
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question how exactly you want to group the results. Can you add your non-working `GROUP BY` clause to the question and tell us the error message you receive, so we can give you a corrected version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregated field to use SUM/MIN based on a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60523554/aggregated-field-to-use-sum-min-based-on-a-condition)